# LibGDX Cursor image pixmap is not in RGBA8888 format

Tags: java, libgdx

I'm trying to change my cursor image by doing this

```
Pixmap pm = new Pixmap(Gdx.files.internal("cursor.png"));
Gdx.input.setCursorImage(pm, 0, 0);
pm.dispose();
```

It's giving me this error

```
Exception in thread "LWJGL Application" com.badlogic.gdx.utils.GdxRuntimeException: Cursor image pixmap is not in RGBA8888 format.
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglInput.setCursorImage(LwjglInput.java:1030)
    at com.bermudez.screen.GameScreen.show(GameScreen.java:25)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.Game.setScreen(Game.java:61)
    at com.bermudez.Game.create(Game.java:16)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication.mainLoop(LwjglApplication.java:143)
    at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication$1.run(LwjglApplication.java:120)
```

Why is this?

Comment: I think it is a libGDX problem. Found this: http://www.badlogicgames.com/wordpress/?p=3758

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably your image is not in a rgba format. You can see the [source code of Cursor](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/blob/master/backends/gdx-backend-lwjgl/src/com/badlogic/gdx/backends/lwjgl/LwjglCursor.java#L34) to check this.

You can check the format with:

```
pm.getFormat();
```

And see if your image `cursor.png` have the proper format (see [this javadoc](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/Pixmap.Format.html)).

Comment: I have the same problem. My bitmap is in format "RGB888". How can I convert this into RGBA8888 format ?